# How to properly integrate an entropy formula?

Tags: integration, entropy

Entropy, denoted as $H$, is

$$ H = - \int_a^b f(x)\log(f(x))\mathsf dx$$

where $f$ is given by the classic:

$$ f(x) = \frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2}.$$

Here is what I have tried so far to analytically solve this integral:

1. Integration by parts (too messy to write all out here), but quickly realized I needed a fancy substitution, thus leading me to:
2. Convert from $x$-space (where the range is $a$ to $b$) to *t*-space (where the range is $\alpha$=$\frac{a-\mu}{\theta}$ to $\beta$=$\frac{b-\mu}{\theta}$) and, in general, $t$=$\frac{x-\mu}{\theta}$.

I think I'm on the right track (the $\theta$ in the denominator nicely cancels using the substitution approach) but I got stuck going from *x*-space to *t*-space and back again (i.e., I'm in *xt*-space purgatory and I want out!).  Can anyone help me make more headway into #2?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ fixed constants? Don't you want to integrate over the range of all possible values for $X$, in which case $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$?

Comment: grand_chat: Great point, yes that would be the general case.  But, in my particular situation, I am dealing with a truncated Gaussian so I have fixed constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hand calculation is not that painful. Fortunately [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) gives the result we are aiming for.

The density of the truncated normal over the interval $[a,b]$ is
$$f(x)=\frac1{\sigma Z}\phi\left({x-\mu\over\sigma}\right)$$
where $\phi$ is the standard normal density and $Z$ is the normalizing constant
$$Z:=\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\,dt\;, $$
where the limits of integration are $\alpha:=(a-\mu)/\sigma$ and $\beta:=(b-\mu)/\sigma$. Using your substitution $t:=(x-\mu)/\sigma$, 
the entropy is
$$
\begin{align}
H&:=-\int_a^bf(x)\log f(x)\,dx
= -\frac1Z\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\log\left(\phi(t)/\sigma Z\right)\,dt\\
&= -\frac1Z\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\log\phi(t)\,dt
+\frac1Z\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\log(\sigma Z)\,dt\\
&= -\frac AZ + B,
\end{align}
$$
where we calculate $B=\log(\sigma Z)$, and
$$
\begin{align}
A&=\int_\alpha^\beta \phi(t)\log\phi(t)\,dt\\
&=\int_\alpha^\beta \phi(t)\left(-{t^2\over2}-\log\sqrt{2\pi}\right)\,dt\\
&=\int_\alpha^\beta -{t^2\over2}\phi(t)\,dt - \int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\log\sqrt{2\pi}\,dt\\
&=C-Z\log\sqrt{2\pi}\;,
\end{align}
$$
and, using integration by parts,
$$\begin{align}
C=\int_\alpha^\beta -{t^2\over2}\phi(t)\,dt
&=\int_\alpha^\beta\frac t2\,d\phi(t)\\
&=\frac t2\phi(t)\left.\right]_\alpha^\beta-\frac12\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\,dt\\
&={\beta\phi(\beta)-\alpha\phi(\alpha)\over2}-\frac Z2\;.
\end{align}
$$
Putting it all together:
$$
\begin{align}
H&=-\frac1Z
\left({\beta\phi(\beta)-\alpha\phi(\alpha)\over2}-\frac Z2-Z\log\sqrt{2\pi}\right)
+\log(\sigma Z)\\
&={\alpha\phi(\alpha)-\beta\phi(\beta)\over2Z}+\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi e}\sigma Z\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm not following your transition from (-A/Z)+B straight into the next argument.  Can you please fill in?

Comment: @warship: should be a little clearer now: we're taking the log of the standard normal density

Comment: I really appreciate it, could you please also fill in the gap where you start using 2pi and, right above it, where you get B=log(theta*Z).  Like how do you go from log(phi(t)) to the polynomial expansion with the 2pi?  This is a very nice proof.

Comment: Just pulling  constants  $\log(\sigma Z)$ and $\log\sqrt{2\pi}$  out of their respective integrals: the constants don't depend on $t$, leaving $\int_\alpha^\beta\phi(t)\,dt$

Comment: .. and log of the standard normal density is $\log[\exp(-t^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}] = \log[\exp(-t^2/2)]-\log[\sqrt{2\pi}]$

Comment: I see your point, but how do you go from log(phi*t) to -t^2/2 - log(sqrt(2pi)) ...

Comment: Looks you cannot join chat ... $\phi(t)$ is defined as $\exp(-t^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: Yes, but this assumes that there is no $\theta$ in the denominator of the $\phi(t)$ expression.  Where did the $\theta$ go?

Comment: When you do the substitution $t=(x-\mu)/\sigma$ you get $dt=dx/\sigma$ so this eats up the $\sigma$ in the denominator of $f(x)=\frac1{\sigma Z}\phi\left({x-\mu\over\sigma}\right)$

Comment: I'm only asking how you go from $f(x)$ (in the original question) to $\phi(t)$.  A $\theta$ goes missing and I've already tried the simple step above.  I don't think we are actually differentiating when we go from one to the other... that's where the source of my problem lies.  This is the only part I don't understand, the rest of the proof makes complete sense to me.

Comment: In other words, there should either be a $\theta$ in the denominator or a $Z$ in the numerator of the $\phi(t)$ expression.  Perhaps $Z$ gets magically absorbed in somehow as a normalizing factor but, as far as I can tell, $\phi(t)=\theta Z f(x)$  From here, obviously, the $\theta$ will cancel, but the Z will remain.  See what I mean?

Comment: I am in chat -- please join

Answer (score 2):

Why try to perform this by hand, rather than symbolically by computer?

$\int\limits_a^b N(\mu, \sigma; x) {\rm ln}(N(\mu, \sigma; x)) dx =$

$
\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(b e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}-a
   e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}\right)+(1+\log (2)+\log (\pi ))
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-(1+\log (2)+\log (\pi ))
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}$

Here's the *Mathemtica* code:

```
FullSimplify@(Assuming[a < b && {a, b} \[Element] Reals, 
   Integrate[
     PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] 
     Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]], 
     {x, a, b}]/
    Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, a, b} ]])
```

which took around 2.5 seconds to run on a MacBook Air.

Comment: As interesting as this approach looks to me, I'm afraid it might be incorrect.  The calculation should involve N(mu,sigma) / Z , not N(mu,sigma) alone especially if you want the entropy of a proper density over [a,b].  As such, you need to incorporate the normalizing constant Z, as shown in the answer of username grand_chat.  Perhaps there is a way to incorporate this into the computer?